# How to set reply-to email in mailgun

Tags: email, elixir, mailgun

I am using Mailgun into my project to sending emails. I want to set `reply-to` email while sending email but there is no information available on Mailgun documentation (https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-in-test-mode).

I am using Elixir to send emails using Mailgun.

Comment: Show us the code you use to send emails.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the [Bamboo Library](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo) from thoughtbot. This makes sending emails really easy in elixir/phoenix and even allows you to set the reply to.

For example, in the "new" email pipeline you would add this transformation:

```
|> put_header("Reply-To", "support@myapp.com")
```

and that will add the header to the email.

Comment: It worth it to mention that `Bamboo` comes with [`Bamboo.MailgunAdapter`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo#adapters).